# What does a `workspace:` prefix in a package.json 'dependencies' value mean?

Tags: babeljs, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Where can I learn more about what is `workspace:` prefix in version number?

For example, in Babel:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "workspace:^7.13.0",
```

[source](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/beb7cf8b24029a31fbadb148d5176ed84bb7a2e1/packages/babel-preset-typescript/package.json#L20)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature of `yarn` 2.x. You can read more about this in the `yarn` documentation at https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces#workspace-ranges-workspace As a snippet:

> For those use cases, Yarn now supports a new resolution protocol starting from the v2: workspace:. When this protocol is used Yarn will refuse to resolve to anything else than a local workspace. This range protocol has two flavors:
>
> - If a semver range, it will select the workspace matching the specified version.
> - If a project-relative path, it will select the workspace that match this path (experimental).

Answer (score -3):

you could check about this dependency via using this command

```
yarn why <dependency-name>
```

Comment: this feature will work in the yarn package manager only.